# Power BI Server with MSSQL Express

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

I've to install Power BI Server but I'm not sure about requirements. I have two questions.

1. `Power BI` can read data from any source. This means I can read data from i.e. `Postgresql` or `MySQL`?
2. `PowerBI` must use `MSSQL 2012` or higher, as repository. Can I use an Express edition as repository?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes you can read from PostGreSQL Databases and MySql - Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-data-sources)
2. You can use PowerBI Desktop with SQL Express but it has some limitations - Read [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Limitations-on-Power-BI-with-SQL-Server-Express/m-p/73501#M30550)
3. You cannot use PowerBI Server - It requires enterprise license.

Comment: The URL from `community.powerBi` is about Data Source database, as *DirectQuery*. I need informations about repository database. I want to use Enterprise Power BI Server without Enterprise SQL Server.

Comment: Yes its about how you use SQL Express. You can only use it with DirectQuery, as it has no SQL Job agent and many more limitations.